# CakePHP How to Search "Users" database table?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a MySQL database for my CakePHP site, and I have a database table with all the users (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxkKr.png).

I already have it so there is a user page that admins can see, which lists all the users.  I want to make it so, at the bottom of the existing user list, there is a search box.  I was trying to use CakePHP queries, but I couldn't get it to work very well, and I was hoping someone could help.  There are of course more rows on the table than I included in that screenshot, those are just the ones that I want to be able to search.

I tried using the basic documentation for what to put into the model, but I couldn't figure out how to make it display the search box or the results, or do any of the filtering.

```
$query = $users
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'contact_no', 'profile_url'])

foreach ($query as $users) {
    debug($users->created);
}
```

A
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I was trying to use CakePHP queries, but I couldn't get it to work very well". Show us what you tried, and explain what's not working about it.

Comment: Use Search plugin, see [this demo](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/search-examples/table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute your query. 
Try the following, It should work fine :

```
$query = $users
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'contact_no', 'profile_url','created'])
    ->toList();

foreach ($query as $users) {
    debug($users->created);
}
```

Comment: may be because 'created' was missing in select([.....]) . Try now